# Emulate Nexus 10

Tags: android

I want to emulate the Nexus 10, but I can't figure out what values to use.
Skin: Built-in or custom resolution? What hardware properties should I use?

Answer (score 2):

I can be quite problematic emulating such a powerful device with the same specs. Unfortunately it is not included into the SDK as Nexus 7.

I suggest using 10-inch WXGA tablet screen (800x1280). And 2GB of RAM. The new AVD Manager does not allow you to specify custom screen size, so it's the closest you can get with emulator.

Generally emulating real 10.055” 2560 x 1600 (300 ppi) screen would be slow I guess.

Also enable "Use host GPU" option for better performance.

Don't forget to add an SD card storage depending on your application needs.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to emulate the Nexus 10 is to use AndroVM. I am currently running Android on it with the full Nexus 10 2560x1600 resolution and it fits onto my HD screen if I set AndroVM to use 320dpi.

Oh.. and it's VERY fast :-)

I personally use it over emulators and real hardware devices as it's extremely responsive.

Update: AndroVM is now called [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/)

Comment: Could you please give instructions how to run AndroVM with nexus 10 resolution ?

Comment: The AndroVM website gives you all the relevant instructions on how to do this. There is an application called AndroVM Player which allows you to specify the resolution. Match that up with the real resolution of the Nexus 10. Also make sure you're using the tablet distribution of AndroVM.